# Google Classroom 503 Service Unavailable Backend Error while Creating Course

Tags: google-api, google-classroom

I have a service that takes a queue of courses created in my SIS and am trying to automatically create them via the Google Classroom API.  I was able to create around 1000 courses and now I am getting the error below:

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
The service is currently unavailable. [503]
Errors [
    Message[The service is currently unavailable.] Location[ - ] Reason[backendError] Domain[global]
]
```

It does not seem to matter what I do, the error still occurs.

Comment: I think this error is most likely due to usage limits on Classroom API. Please check this link https://developers.google.com/classroom/limits Let me know if you still see the issue.

Comment: I checked and I don't see my limits reached in the developers console.  In fact, I don't see anything showing up in developers console.

Comment: This also only happens on one domain, my client's domain.  On my own test domain the EXACT same code runs perfectly.

Comment: I also got this error. I can confirm that I was far a way from any quota limit. Same request worked normally after some period (~20-30 min).

In my case, Google script started delaying execution, from 50ms to few seconds(without any reason, as far as I could debug), and after few requests it started returning same error message as Ariana wrote. Are there any update on this?

Answer (score 3):

This is a regular occurrence with Google APIs. It's the method which Google servers use to say "you're going to fast slow down". In order to handle this, well behaved API clients should implement [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/limits#backoff).

So for example, your script can create courses as fast as it can as long as it's getting HTTP 2xx success responses from Google. As soon as it sees a 503 back end error, it should pause all calls for 1 second and then retry the failed operation. Very often on 2nd try the operation will succeed but if it doesn't your script should pause 2 seconds, then 4, 8, etc, etc until success. I recommend maxing out at 10 tries and then failing with an error.

If your script does not do backoff and just continues to retry API calls with no pause, you are likely to see an increase in errors like this and your script may be blacklisted eventually.

Comment: I had a script I had run overnight.  I will add the code for the exponential backoff, but if my script is blacklisted, what do I do?